# How long will it take the average person to finish a test with $X$ questions.

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

I'm trying to create an algorithm that calculates the time spent on a test with the following data. The difficulty I'm having is that there are some outliers which skew the data. For instance a test with 4 question takes 6740 seconds while a test with 5 questions only takes 380. Also, it only goes up to 99 and I'd like it to go much higher even though my samples doesn't.

```
Average time on 4 tests with 99 questions: 1776 seconds (30 minutes)
Average time on 2 tests with 98 questions: 1418 seconds (24 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 97 questions: 1726 seconds (29 minutes)
Average time on 1 tests with 96 questions: 1233 seconds (21 minutes)
Average time on 3 tests with 95 questions: 4613 seconds (77 minutes)
Average time on 4 tests with 94 questions: 653 seconds (11 minutes)
Average time on 1 tests with 93 questions: 1415 seconds (24 minutes)
Average time on 3 tests with 92 questions: 4899 seconds (82 minutes)
Average time on 5 tests with 91 questions: 906 seconds (15 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 90 questions: 2218 seconds (37 minutes)

Average time on 12 tests with 89 questions: 2082 seconds (35 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 88 questions: 1042 seconds (17 minutes)
Average time on 3 tests with 87 questions: 1939 seconds (32 minutes)
Average time on 5 tests with 86 questions: 1098 seconds (18 minutes)
Average time on 4 tests with 85 questions: 4689 seconds (78 minutes)
Average time on 6 tests with 84 questions: 1498 seconds (25 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 83 questions: 912 seconds (15 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 82 questions: 4051 seconds (68 minutes)
Average time on 3 tests with 81 questions: 5219 seconds (87 minutes)
Average time on 12 tests with 80 questions: 1699 seconds (28 minutes)

Average time on 7 tests with 79 questions: 1869 seconds (31 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 78 questions: 2301 seconds (38 minutes)
Average time on 7 tests with 77 questions: 3950 seconds (66 minutes)
Average time on 8 tests with 76 questions: 38215 seconds (637 minutes)
Average time on 44 tests with 75 questions: 1748 seconds (29 minutes)
Average time on 8 tests with 74 questions: 1210 seconds (20 minutes)
Average time on 8 tests with 73 questions: 878 seconds (15 minutes)
Average time on 66 tests with 72 questions: 2903 seconds (48 minutes)
Average time on 18 tests with 71 questions: 1948 seconds (32 minutes)
Average time on 12 tests with 70 questions: 2179 seconds (36 minutes)

Average time on 12 tests with 69 questions: 655 seconds (11 minutes)
Average time on 12 tests with 68 questions: 1879 seconds (31 minutes)
Average time on 13 tests with 67 questions: 1747 seconds (29 minutes)
Average time on 15 tests with 66 questions: 2567 seconds (43 minutes)
Average time on 25 tests with 65 questions: 3719 seconds (62 minutes)
Average time on 19 tests with 64 questions: 2457 seconds (41 minutes)
Average time on 18 tests with 63 questions: 1090 seconds (18 minutes)
Average time on 23 tests with 62 questions: 1157 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 34 tests with 61 questions: 1227 seconds (20 minutes)
Average time on 29 tests with 60 questions: 3446 seconds (57 minutes)

Average time on 13 tests with 59 questions: 2113 seconds (35 minutes)
Average time on 22 tests with 58 questions: 4645 seconds (77 minutes)
Average time on 36 tests with 57 questions: 1177 seconds (20 minutes)
Average time on 79 tests with 56 questions: 2362 seconds (39 minutes)
Average time on 23 tests with 55 questions: 1142 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 47 tests with 54 questions: 3707 seconds (62 minutes)
Average time on 35 tests with 53 questions: 1138 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 67 tests with 52 questions: 1685 seconds (28 minutes)
Average time on 43 tests with 51 questions: 1049 seconds (17 minutes)
Average time on 78 tests with 50 questions: 1427 seconds (24 minutes)

Average time on 59 tests with 49 questions: 1042 seconds (17 minutes)
Average time on 52 tests with 48 questions: 1401 seconds (23 minutes)
Average time on 50 tests with 47 questions: 2648 seconds (44 minutes)
Average time on 79 tests with 46 questions: 1675 seconds (28 minutes)
Average time on 92 tests with 45 questions: 1645 seconds (27 minutes)
Average time on 75 tests with 44 questions: 1963 seconds (33 minutes)
Average time on 102 tests with 43 questions: 1953 seconds (33 minutes)
Average time on 100 tests with 42 questions: 1591 seconds (27 minutes)
Average time on 119 tests with 41 questions: 2934 seconds (49 minutes)
Average time on 124 tests with 40 questions: 2832 seconds (47 minutes)

Average time on 125 tests with 39 questions: 1796 seconds (30 minutes)
Average time on 147 tests with 38 questions: 1559 seconds (26 minutes)
Average time on 173 tests with 37 questions: 1120 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 189 tests with 36 questions: 1944 seconds (32 minutes)
Average time on 238 tests with 35 questions: 1558 seconds (26 minutes)
Average time on 185 tests with 34 questions: 1434 seconds (24 minutes)
Average time on 247 tests with 33 questions: 1337 seconds (22 minutes)
Average time on 262 tests with 32 questions: 1511 seconds (25 minutes)
Average time on 285 tests with 31 questions: 1403 seconds (23 minutes)
Average time on 496 tests with 30 questions: 1245 seconds (21 minutes)

Average time on 369 tests with 29 questions: 1370 seconds (23 minutes)
Average time on 445 tests with 28 questions: 1254 seconds (21 minutes)
Average time on 512 tests with 27 questions: 1289 seconds (21 minutes)
Average time on 574 tests with 26 questions: 1457 seconds (24 minutes)
Average time on 873 tests with 25 questions: 1271 seconds (21 minutes)
Average time on 806 tests with 24 questions: 1096 seconds (18 minutes)
Average time on 841 tests with 23 questions: 1146 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 922 tests with 22 questions: 1110 seconds (19 minutes)
Average time on 1211 tests with 21 questions: 1890 seconds (32 minutes)
Average time on 2034 tests with 20 questions: 889 seconds (15 minutes)

Average time on 1290 tests with 19 questions: 1074 seconds (18 minutes)
Average time on 1594 tests with 18 questions: 829 seconds (14 minutes)
Average time on 1754 tests with 17 questions: 895 seconds (15 minutes)
Average time on 2153 tests with 16 questions: 2446 seconds (41 minutes)
Average time on 3107 tests with 15 questions: 821 seconds (14 minutes)
Average time on 2483 tests with 14 questions: 722 seconds (12 minutes)
Average time on 2741 tests with 13 questions: 964 seconds (16 minutes)
Average time on 3074 tests with 12 questions: 713 seconds (12 minutes)
Average time on 3229 tests with 11 questions: 837 seconds (14 minutes)
Average time on 5299 tests with 10 questions: 939 seconds (16 minutes)

Average time on 3165 tests with 9 questions: 704 seconds (12 minutes)
Average time on 3749 tests with 8 questions: 650 seconds (11 minutes)
Average time on 3857 tests with 7 questions: 484 seconds (8 minutes)
Average time on 4605 tests with 6 questions: 574 seconds (10 minutes)
Average time on 5273 tests with 5 questions: 380 seconds (6 minutes)
Average time on 3833 tests with 4 questions: 6740 seconds (112 minutes)
Average time on 4046 tests with 3 questions: 261 seconds (4 minutes)
Average time on 4536 tests with 2 questions: 176 seconds (3 minutes)
Average time on 7740 tests with 1 questions: 210 seconds (4 minutes)
```

I thought about grouping them into sets of 10 the taking the median but I lose some details and it's still not as accurate.

```
99-90 median: 1418 seconds
89-80 median: 1939 seconds
79-70 median: 1948 seconds
69-60 median: 1747 seconds
59-50 median: 1685 seconds
49-40 median: 1675 seconds
39-30 median: 1511 seconds
29-20 median: 1271 seconds
19-10 median: 837 seconds
9-1 median: 529 seconds
```

Is there some kind of formula I can use where I can plug in the number of questions ($X$) and get the time the test should take to complete based on this data?

Comment: Well, you could try a regression.  Linear first.  Is the number of seconds reasonably close to a linear function of the number of questions?  You could plot this first to see if it "looked linear".  There are polynomial regressions as well.  Generally, it is a good idea to have some idea in advance as to what sort of function you expect the answer to be.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the reply. If only I knew, I'm woefully uninformed when it comes to mathematics

Comment: Well, lots of numerical software packages have linear regressions built in.  Excel for example.   It should be easy enough to try.  At a quick glance, it sure doesn't look linear (even if we ignore the improbable observation that people could do $95$ questions dramatically faster than they could do $85$ questions).